# Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.dll' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I'm trying to use CefSharp to load my web app into winfoms. I've added 2 dll files: CefSharp.dll and CefSharp.WinForms into references and add 2 dll files icudt.dll and libcef.dll into my project through add existing items.
[image]

and this is the code from the form

```
public WebView web_view;

public Form1()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     web_view = new WebView("http://localhost:8084/wsmill",new CefSharp.BrowserSettings());
     web_view.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
     toolStripContainer1.ContentPanel.Controls.Add(web_view);
     CefSharp.CEF.Initialize(new Settings());
}
```

When run the app, I got this error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred
>   in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe
>        Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.dll' or one of its dependencies. A dynamic link library
>   (DLL) initialization routine failed. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8007045A)

So anyone who know about this please help me, thanks

Comment: install Visual C++ Redistributable 2012. It should work.

Comment: FYI, Norton Antivirus will try to quarantine cefsharp.dll .

Comment: As ARUNRAJ said Install this: https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Answer (score 26):

You need to put these files

```
libcef.dll
icudtl.dat
CefSharp.dll
CefSharp.WinForms.dll
```

into your **bin\Debug** (or *bin\Release*, based on your configuration).

And please do not forget to install **Visual C++ 2012 Redistribution** (Visual C++ **2013** Redistributable since version 43). If you don't, Visual Studio will always display an exception saying CefSharp.dll is not found even though you already have it.

Comment: At least with my install the 2nd file should be icudtl.dat, not icudt.dll. Note the "l" after the "t" before ".dat".

Comment: icudtl.dat is the Unicode support file not icudt.dll
See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Output-files-description-table-(Redistribution)

Answer (score 8):

This is a common error which is caused by not having all required files in the output directory (bin\Debug or bin\Release, depending on which configuration you are running in Visual Studio). `CefSharp.dll` is a .NET-based DLL which is dependent on other .dll files, which in turn depends further on other .dll and other files.

Here is a listing of the minimum required files:

- **libcef.dll** (The core Chromium DLL, which basically contains the web
  browser + the CEF embeddability interface which we depend on)
- **icudt.dll** (Unicode DLL for Chromium, must also be present)
- **CefSharp.dll** (managed .NET assembly which contains the core CefSharp
  functionality)
- **CefSharp.WinForms.dll** or **CefSharp.WPF.dll** (depending on your project
  type)

See [CefSharp - Frequently asked questions](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions).

Comment: So how can I add libcef and icudt, I know that it's win32 dll not a .net dll so I can't add it like a reference, follow the instruction from microsoft, I did like above, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 7):

This is a common problem and is therefore mentioned in the [FAQ](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions), question number 3.

@AcccessDenied is right. The files need to be present in your output folder (bin\Debug or bin\Release). One way to make this is by using a `Post-Build` action, which can set under the project settings in Visual Studio.

You can also set up the post-build in the `.csproj` file, somewhat like this:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <ItemGroup>
    <CefBinaries Include="$(SolutionDir)CEF\$(UnmanagedPlatform)\*.*" />
    <LocaleFiles Include="$(SolutionDir)CEF\locales\*.*" />
    <SubProcessFiles Include="$(SolutionDir)$(UnmanagedPlatform)\$(Configuration)\CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(CefBinaries)" DestinationFolder="$(TargetDir)" />
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(LocaleFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(TargetDir)locales" />
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(SubProcessFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(TargetDir)" />
</Target>
```

(This example is taken from the [CefSharp.Wpf.Example](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/CefSharp3/CefSharp.Wpf.Example/CefSharp.Wpf.Example.csproj#L161) project in the CefSharp source code, CefSharp3 branch. The exact file locations may vary in your case, especially if using CefSharp1, so adapt it as needed to ensure the files get copied correctly.)

I don't recommend putting stuff in bin\Debug or bin\Release and adding it to the solution using `Copy Always`. It feels like a kludge to me.

Comment: This solution is cleaner than the top upvoted answer, it doesn't match the NuGet CefSharp dir structure but it gives you the general idea.

Answer (score 7):

I have just had problems with this as well and I did the following:

- check that all files are in the apps root directory (https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Output-files-description-table-%28Redistribution%29 and https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/src/aefb5ccce879f308f0bcc3ac719c86defe2f9715/tools/distrib/win/README.redistrib.txt?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)
- made sure the C++ Redist was installed (in fact I have 2010, 2013, 2015 all x86 and x64 installed)
- added the following code during startup to ensure all dependencies are there

  ```
      string dir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
      var missingDeps = CefSharp.DependencyChecker.CheckDependencies(true, false, dir, string.Empty,
          Path.Combine(dir, "CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe"));
      if (missingDeps?.Count > 0)
          throw new InvalidOperationException("Missing components:\r\n  " + string.Join("\r\n  ", missingDeps));
      // ReSharper disable once UnusedVariable
      var browser = new CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser(); //test, if browser can be instantiated
  ```

`CefSharp.DependencyChecker` did not report anything missing but as soon as I called new `CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser()` the exception occured.

I checked all ms.net CEF dlls using ILSpy and found that some of these DLLs were also located in the GAC. As soon as I removed them from GAC all worked ok!

Comment: THANK YOU. I've been reading all the answers online, including the FAQ, and they all left out a couple of components that the DependencyChecker found.

Answer (score 3):

I had offline CEF working perfectly, then it suddenly stopped working after upgrading solution to core 3.1.  Still not sure why, but copying in resources, VC++ runtimes, etc. and other usual solutions didn't work.  I added the following code for diagnostic purposes in my startup code and suddenly, CEF works again.  Assemblies were in same path, but it seems loading them clued in the assembly binder.  If anyone is similarly frustrated, might try similar approach with whatever variant of CEF assemblies you are working with.  Maybe some .net gurus can explain exactly why this helps.

```
  try
  {
    Assembly asm;
    string path;

    path = Path.Combine(
      Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
      "CefSharp.Core.dll");
    asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
    path = Path.Combine(
      Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
      "CefSharp.OffScreen.dll");
    asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
  }
  catch (Exception exception)
  {
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(exception.Message + " @ " + exception.StackTrace);
  }
```

*** Updates below after @amaitland offered the pertinent information, thanks!
As per https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample#net-core-support I updated my project to include:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Update="CefSharp">
    <Private>true</Private>
  </Reference>
  <Reference Update="CefSharp.Core">
    <Private>true</Private>
  </Reference>
  <Reference Update="CefSharp.OffScreen">
    <Private>true</Private>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

and it no longer needs the previous code block to work out of the box.  If anyone runs into confusion like I did, adding privateassets all to the PACKAGE reference is not the same thing.  Rather than typing in those lines, you can also expand 'Assemblies' in the solution explorer for your project, and right click on the CefSharp assemblies there and change CopyLocal to Yes.  Thanks again, @amaitland

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample#net-core-support specifically you need to add entries to your project https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/master/CefSharp.MinimalExample.OffScreen/CefSharp.MinimalExample.OffScreen.netcore.csproj#L17

Comment: @amaitland Thank you!!!  That explains it.  I was having trouble at first because via nuget the are project references and setting privateassets all there was having no effect, but adding separate itemgroup with private true works!

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the 'copy to output' properties of the files to 'copy always' or 'copy if newer'.
This copies all the files to the output directory, as stated by Coder.

Comment: it still throws the error no matter I changed it to copy always or copy if newer

Comment: @KienDangNgoc did you resolve this as i m facing the same issue

Comment: actually adding those two directly into my bin release and  setting 'copy to output' worked for me thanks c_wiz_kid

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was following the steps outlined in [CefSharp - Our Code World](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/173/how-to-use-cefsharp-chromium-embedded-framework-csharp-in-a-winforms-application).

Instead of following step A and adding `CefSharpAnyCpuSupport` in `csproj` and `probing` in `App.config`, simply setting the `Platform Target` to `x86` in step B did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way seems to be to use the NuGet package. Even then you need to make some non-intuitive changes but they are documented. When installing the package freshly a **readme.txt file opens** with most common issues.

In my case I was missing (x64 also available)

```
<probing privatePath="x86" />
```

My App.config looks like this (with CommonServiceLocator in it, ignore that part if you don't have it)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2" />
    </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="x86" />

      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CommonServiceLocator" publicKeyToken="489b6accfaf20ef0" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.3.0" newVersion="2.0.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

The error occurs because there is really no Cefsharp DLL in the bin folder when you set the project to AnyCPU. But in the x86 and x64 folder bellow where you are probing when adding this line the DLL exists. A temporary fix would be to copy the contents from /bin/x86 to /bin.

If AnyCpu is desired CefSharpAnyCpuSupport needs to be added to csproj file. The project Flag for Prefer 32bit needs to be set.

Comment: The files are only copied into x86 and x64 sub folders when you choose AnyCpu, if you pick x86 or x64 as your solution target then the files will be copied directly into the bin folder. Setting probing privatePath as you suggest on an x64 will crash unless your executable is set to prefer 32bit.

Comment: Note that you must set x86/x64 at the solution level to use that approach, just changing for your individual project won't work. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample for a working example

Comment: Thanks for your input. I updated my question to mention x64 and the reason of selecting AnyCPU

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure all dependent libraries are copied to debug/release folder
2. If you build CEFSharp libs by your own, make sure the build configuration matches. That is, if you build your application in Release mode , x86 then you must build CEFSharp libs also in Release, x86. Other wise it will throw dll not found error

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I found that one of the project platform is mentioned as x64. I changed it to "Any CPU" it works fine.

Answer (score -3):

Setting "msvcp120.dll" and "msvcr120.dll" to "Copy Always" helped me.