# Could not load file or assembly "CerfSharp.Core.dll" or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found

Tags: c#, chromium, cefsharp, oneclick

I have installed CerfSharp using the NuGet Pakage Manager and published a simple project that loads a ChromiumWebBrowser instance using the OneClick publish wizard.
However when installing the publised application the following error is diplayed "Could not load file or assembly "CerfSharp.Core.dll" or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found." if I click "ok" and run the application the ChromeWebBrowser doesn't work.
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLRnV.jpg)

Can anyone provide the steps necessary in order to correctly build and pack the necessary files?

Other References:

- https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/173/how-to-use-cefsharp-chromium-embedded-framework-csharp-in-a-winforms-application
- [Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.dll' or one of its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203077/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-cefsharp-dll-or-one-of-its-dependencies)

[System Info]:

- Cef version: 63.0.0.0
- OS: 
  Windows 10 x64  [Version 10.0.16299.248]
- Visual Studio Version:

  - Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017
  - Version 15.0.26228.12 D15RTWSVC
  - Microsoft .NET Framework
  - Version 4.7.02556

Comment: I assume you followed the resolution in the "could not load" stackoverflow question you referenced? Have you also checked that the reference is actually being distributed?

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kzy0fky2.aspx

Comment: Yep, I've just verified this https://imgur.com/a/kQRRi

Comment: Search CefSharp clickonce with your fav search engine